# обновить div по событию

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вопрос как обновить блок  который в корзине, по событию, в смысле что бы сразу как событие сработало - то div обновился.
Прошу помочь написать пример такого калбека

Есть механизм корзины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии кнопки купить срабатывает событие, в виде количества отправки в корзину
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в корзине с лева инфа обновляется только через обновление окна браузера либо уходу на другую страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

cart.view.small_info.php

```
    $goods = '%s товаров на %s';
    if($result["count"] == 1)
    {
        $goods = '%s товар на %s';
    }
    elseif($result["count"] > 1 && $result["count"] < 5)
    {
        $goods = '%s товара на %s';
    }

echo $this->diafan->_($goods, true, $result["count"], $result["summ"].'&nbsp;'.$result["currency"]);
```

cart.view.show_block_mini_cart.php

```
echo '<div class="block-content cart_disp">';
echo '<p class="empty" id="show_cart">'.$this->get('small_info', 'cart', $result).'</p>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Приведите примеры кода, где вы пытались решить задачу

Comment: я бы привел, но все в разных файлах, мне просто нужен пример как обновить определенный див который получает данные из пхп по событию(хоть по вымышленной кнопке)

Comment: Вы используете ajax?

Comment: у меня есть представление как заставить работать ajax'om но...

обновил главный пост

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
  $('#basket').append('<div><span>Педаль</span><strong> 3000 руб.</strong></div>');
});
```

```css
#basket {
  width: 200px;
}
#basket > div {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="basket">
  <div>
    <span>Картошка</span>
    <strong> 50 руб.</strong>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Лось</span>
    <strong> 150 руб.</strong>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="add">Добавить Педаль</button>
```

Далее уже можно накручивать всё, что душе угодно ... в том числе и ajax, хотя нужды я пока в нем не вижу ...

Comment: это все хорошо, но `echo '<p class="empty" id="show_cart">'.$this->get('small_info', 'cart', $result).'</p>` выводит уже готовый результат, но он не отобразиться пока не обновить страницу, мне нужно что бы по клику сработало обновление, но не страницы, а определенного дива где он у меня есть `<div class="cart">
<insert name="show_block" module="cart" template="mini_cart">
</div>` - этот див мне нужно обновить по клику на купить

Comment: Я Вам написал пример добавления записи в блок. Вы спокойно можете  данные, для добавления товара в блок карзины, записывать в data параметре кнопки "Купить" (и брать при клике оттуда же), а содержание карзины в localStorage или cookies ...

Comment: а можно попросить демку с примерами печенек:) или же как вы сказали с localStorage

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie